# Функция возвращает неверное значение после проверки через if. PHP

Tags: php, cookie, jwt, refresh

**Если что, тут будет много кода!**

Возникла проблема которую сложно объяснить.
У меня есть функция которая возвращает либо `true`, или `false`.
Называется она `isLogin();` Функция статическая.

Например, если я хочу попасть на страницу под названием "Информация", то что бы туда попасть, нужна быть авторизованным пользователем. Авторизация пользователя проверяется с помощи функции `isLogin()`, в файле `User.php` (еще класс `User`); isLogin проверяет валидность токена (JWT).

Делаю я так:

```
    <?php

class Information extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(User::isLogin()); // тут будет уже true
        echo "<br>";
        if(User::isLogin()){
            parent::__construct();
            var_dump(User::isLogin()); // Тут будет уже false 
        }else{
            header('location:'.'/login/');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

После перезагрузки страницы User::isLogin() везде возвращает true, пока не дойдет до обновление токена (см. ниже).

`parent::__construct(); — вызывает функцию index, а inedx отображает страницу "Информация".`

**Что делает isLogin:**

```
static function isLogin(){
    $isLogin = User::validateToken();
    var_dump($isLogin); // isLogin равно массив данных
    if($isLogin != false){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Переменная $isLogin принимает либо false, либо массив данных.

*validateToken(); — проверяет на валидность токена и его срок жизни. Если он не верный, то возвращает false (return false). Если он верный то возвращает $payload (return $payload). $payload если что возвращается расшифрованным для того что бы его использовать.*

Функция validateToken():

```
static function validateToken(){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['token']) && $_COOKIE['token']){
            $key = '5a7234753778214125442a472d4b6150645267556b58703273357638792f423f';
            $token = $_COOKIE['token'];
            $arrayData = explode(".", $token);

            $sign_new = hash_hmac('SHA256', $arrayData[0] . '.' . $arrayData[1], $key, true);
            $sign_new = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($sign_new), '+/', '-_'), '=');

            if($sign_new == $arrayData[2]){
                $playload = rtrim(strtr(base64_decode($arrayData[1]), '+/', '-_'), '=');
                $playload = json_decode($playload);
                $timezone = $playload->exp;
                if(time() > $timezone){ //Если время истекло то ...
                    $id = $playload->uid; //Я беру id пользователя
                    $data = User::updateSuccessToken($id); //Потом вызываю функцию. После возвращение её результатов и происходит такая фигня. Она возвращает либо false, или payload От нового токена, без его проверки.
                    if($data != false){
                        return $data;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }else{
                    /*$playload = rtrim(strtr(base64_decode($arrayData[1]), '+/', '-_'), '=');*/
                    return $playload;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Вроде бы все хорошо, вот если так оставить то все будет работать.
**Но! Если у токена срок действия истек, я вызываю функцию** `updateSuccessToken($id)`;

*updateSuccessToken($id); — делает почти все тоже самое. Она проверяет на валидность refresh token, и если он валидный, то удаляет куки, и создает новые (JWT и Refresh) токены и без проверки выданного токена(JWT) возвращает только данные, или false если (старый)refresh токен например неправильный или его срок действия истек.*

Я воткну код этой функции здесь:

```
static function updateSuccessToken($id){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['refresh_token'])){
            $db = new Database();
            $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, login, role, refresh_token, time_refresh_token FROM users WHERE "
            ."id= :id");
            $sth->execute(array(
                ':id' => $id,
            ));
            if($sth->rowCount() > 0){
                $data = $sth->fetch();
                $refresh_token_user = $_COOKIE['refresh_token'];
                if($data["refresh_token"] == $refresh_token_user){
                    if(time() < $data["time_refresh_token"]){
                        User::logout(); // Удаление двух куки с JWT, и Refresh.
                        $key = '5a7234753778214125442a472d4b6150645267556b58703273357638792f423f';
                        $date = new DateTime();

                        $header = [
                            'typ' => 'JWT',
                            'alg' => 'HS256'
                        ];

                        $payload = [
                            'exp' => time()+5,
                            'uid' => $data["id"],
                            'login' => $data["login"],
                            'role' => $data["role"]
                        ];

                        // JSON
                        $header = json_encode($header);
                        $payload = json_encode($payload);

                        // BASE 64
                        $header = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($header), '+/', '-_'), '=');
                        $payload = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($payload), '+/', '-_'), '=');

                        // Assinature
                        $sing = hash_hmac('SHA256', $header . '.' . $payload, $key, true);
                        $sing = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($sing), '+/', '-_'), '=');

                        $refresh_token = User::gen_refresh_token(16, $lastword);

                        $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `refresh_token` = :refresh_token WHERE `id` = :id");
                        $sth->execute(array('refresh_token' => $refresh_token, 'id' => $data["id"]));

                        //TOKEN
                        $token = $header . '.' . $payload . '.' . $sing;
                        $payload = rtrim(strtr(base64_decode($payload), '+/', '-_'), '=');
                        $payload = json_decode($payload);
                        setcookie("token", $token, time() + 600, '/'); //Устанавливаю новые куки JWT
                        setcookie("refresh_token", $refresh_token, time() + 600, '/'); //Устанавливаю новые куки refresh
                        return $payload; // Возвращаю данные
                    }else{
                        return false; //Если что то пошло не так
                    }
                }else{
                    return false; //Если что то пошло не так
                }
            }else{
                return false; //Если что то пошло не так
            }
        }else{
            return false; //Если что то пошло не так
        }
    }
```

Да, реализация JWT и обновление их с помощи Refresh выглядит странно, и даже может быть убога. Но я новечок, а реализации обновление токена не нашел!

**Прошу вас помочь! Я уже куча времени потратил на это, просто тестирую свой код и изменяя его, без результата. Помогите пожалуйста!**

**UPD:**

Возможно потому что я реализую MVC. Если есть возможность то подскажите как реализовать обновление токена в php. Просто сообщить м не в каком файле это делать, как и что туда вписывть, а самое главное как после обновление переходить на ту страницу которая ты изначально нажал.

Как делаю я:
Что бы зайти на страницу я создаю контроллер, потом модель, потом view.
Набираю в url - information, я вызываю потом класс под названием information, если у information нет методов, я просто вызываю его и там уже идет проверка (см. выше, самое первое).

Код app.php

```
<?php
//Контроль над url!

class App{
    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            $url = explode('/', rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'));
        }else{
            $url[0] = 'index';
        }
        $file_name = 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
        if(file_exists($file_name)){
            ////Подключениеи контроллера
            require_once $file_name;
            $controller = new $url[0];
            //Вызов метода
            if(isset($url[1])){
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                    if(isset($url[2])){
                        $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
                    }else{
                        $controller->{$url[1]}();
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "Такого метода <b>".$url[1]."</b> файла: <b>".$url[0].".php</b> Не сущестует";
                }
            }else{
                $controller->index();
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Такого файла: <b>'.$url[0].'.php</b> не существует';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `User::logout();` и действительно, почему же `User::isLogin() = false`

Comment: Доброго времени вам! Спасибо хоть что вы откликнулись. 
logout я реализую вот так: https://snipboard.io/jaQV6B.jpg (скрин).
Убрал я её, все равно тоже самое, какая то мистика, вроде бы все должно работать но не работает. Потому что я когда обновляю токен, кидаю в куки и jwt и refresh.

Comment: Куки вот меняются, Но когда они меняются как раз и User::isLogin = false, и данных не каких нет. Не знаю почему. После logout я снизу добавляю новые куки с токенами. И если произошло обновление то куки я больше не трогаю, а просо передаю новые данные вот так: `return $payload`; в метод который обновляет куки

Comment: приложите лучше код `isLogin`, и не в комментарии и скриншоте, а в вопросе, нажав на кнопку "Править"

Comment: Можете уточнить? Я наверное не правильно понял, или вы ошиблись. Я уже выкладывал код функции `isLogin()`, там есть его реализация.

Comment: Пропустил, извините. Советую вам в функции `updateSuccessToken` и `validateToken` в блоки с false добавить логирование. Так вы поймёте из-за чего у вас isLogin становится `false`. Дальше будет проще. Если у вас не подключен логгер, то можно воспользоваться https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trigger-error.php

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Таким я еще не занимался, возможно что то узнаю а в лучшем случаи найду проблему!
Я попробовал сначала в переменную создать и туда результаты isLogin().
`$isL = User::isLogin();` потом проверку. Теперь у меня все нормально, но только потому что я сделал перезагрузку страницы 2 раза. 

Спасибо что пытались помочь мне. Сложно и утомительно наверное ковыряться в чужом коде, поэтому мало кто отвечает. Спасибо за направление.

Не могли бы вы еще сказать, сама реализация обновление токена правильно? Или все таки по другому нужно? Если по другому то можно мини пример?

Comment: Пример не кода. А например какой файл создавать, где и как, и как его запускать, и так далее. Ну или достаточно да или нет!

Comment: с этим не помогу т.к. не работал с jwt